# Notched corner rectangles in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I've been trying to figure out a way to create notched/clipped corners in React Native all night.  It seems like something that would be super easy to do but it's apparently not.  I'm guessing SVG is maybe the right call.  Would love to control the corners independently.  How can I make this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a button like this by combination of 3 View: Top notched view, the rectangular central button with text and bottom notched view, your component should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View
} from 'react-native';

const NotchedButton = ({ width, color }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={{
      ...styles.notchStyle, borderBottomWidth: 10, borderBottomColor: color, width
    }}
    />
    <View style={{ ...styles.centerViewStyle, width, backgroundColor: color }}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Button</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{
      ...styles.notchStyle, borderTopWidth: 10, borderTopColor: color, width
    }}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

NotchedButton.defaultProps = {
  width: '90%',
  color: 'red',
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  notchStyle: {
    height: 10,
    borderLeftWidth: 10,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: 10,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderStyle: 'solid'
  },
  centerViewStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: 50
  },
  textStyle: { fontSize: 24, color: 'white' }
});

export default NotchedButton;
```

This component will look like this:

[image]

You can extract properties from this component as props like button text, width, height, color...

For complex react-native shapes I recommend this excellent [tutorial](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native), every time I need a complex ui I follow this tutorial and I find what I want.

Comment: this works!  question though:  since this is taking several shapes and overlaying them, there'd be no way to make the button transparent with just a border on the outline right?  if I wanted to have that behavior, would the only option in RN be learning how to create svg paths?

Comment: I can't say if it's possible or not to make a border to a component like this using react native, I tried a little but I didn't find any solution.. I think that you should ask another question so more experienced people can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below example which enables you to control the corners independently. But for that, you have to wrap four different `View` inside your button.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => console.log("Button Clicked")}
      style={styles.buttonStyle}
    >
      <View style={styles.cutOffTopLeft} />
      <View style={styles.cutOffTopRight} />
      <View style={styles.cutOffBottomLeft} />
      <View style={styles.cutOffBottomRight} />
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>START 30-DAY FREE TRIAL</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    margin: 20,
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    marginVertical: 13,
  },
  cutOffTopLeft: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    borderRightWidth: 10,
    borderTopWidth: 10,
    borderTopColor: "white",
    borderRightColor: "transparent",
  },
  cutOffTopRight: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: 10,
    borderTopWidth: 10,
    borderTopColor: "white",
    borderLeftColor: "transparent",
  },
  cutOffBottomLeft: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    borderRightWidth: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 10,
    borderBottomColor: "white",
    borderRightColor: "transparent",
  },
  cutOffBottomRight: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 10,
    borderBottomColor: "white",
    borderLeftColor: "transparent",
  },
});
```

This may not be the optimal solution.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts

Comment: This is close but the corners aren't transparent unfortunately

Comment: @BradHerman Since it is a separate view you can't provide a transparent color. but if you want to change the color of corners according to the parent view pass corner color as props.